# Initializing an array of cstring inside a function call

Tags: c, cstring

How come I can do this:

```
char sXSongs[20][30] = {"Song 1", "Song 2 (w/Blur)", "The End (It's Not Here Yet)"};
addAlbum(&list, "The Beatles", "Some Famous CD", 1960, sXSongs);
```

But not this:

```
addAlbum(&list, "The Beatles", "Some Famous CD", 1960, {"Song 1", "Song 2 (w/Blur)", "The End (It's Not Here Yet)"});
```

Is it impossible to initialize an array of cstrings inside a function call?

Here are some other tidbits of information:

```
album* list = NULL;
typedef struct album {
    char performer[20];
    char CDtitle[50];
    int year;
    char songs[20][30];
    struct album* prev;
    struct album* next;
} album;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is possible to initialize an array when declaring it, not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate like that in C++.

It's possible (sort-of) in C# if you use anonymous types that you can create on the fly.